# How to avoid js function call on page refresh

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a js function which is called from code behind(on a button click event) which opens a modal window. No problem with the button click event or js function calling the modal window. But the main problem come's if I refresh the page. Whenever I refresh the page, the js function is called without clicking on any button and loading the modal window.

How can I avoid this modal window loading on page refresh?

Here is my code.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showModal() {
            $('#viewOc').modal();
            return false;
        };
    </script>
</head>

<body>
     <asp:button class="btn btn-default" id="btnTextView" runat="server" Text="View as Text" commandArgument="1234" OnCommand="btnTextView_View">   </asp:button>
     <div class="modal fade" id="viewOc" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                   //some content here
                </div>
            </div>
     </div>
</body>

protected void btnTextView_View(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {
            //some processing here
            if (!ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("JSScript"))
            {
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "JSScript",
                @"<script type='text/javascript'>showModal()</script>");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135404/btnadd-click-fires-when-i-press-f5 @ASN

Answer (score 0):

If the function in the code-behind you shared is causing the JS to run, you can modify it as follows:

```
protected void btnTextView_View(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
      //some processing here
      if (!ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("JSScript") && !Page.IsPostBack)
      {
          ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "JSScript",
                @"<script type='text/javascript'>showModal()</script>");
      }
}
```

EDIT:
As per your comment, I understand that if the page is refreshed, the event for the button is fired again. This is a known issue with webpages resubmitting the request and you should take a look at this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10240/Detecting-Page-Refresh) to solve your problem. It's lengthy but gets the job done!

Comment: i think you just added this code. `&& !Page.IsPostBack`. When I added this, Its not even calling the js function on button click.

Comment: Are you sure this is the snippet responsible for the popup to show on every postback.. I'm confused with the flow here

Comment: try with `&& Page.IsPostBack` .... you would need the script if page is posted back... @ASN

Comment: @SamGhatak This time I'm able to load the modal window on button click. But still having the problem on page refresh.

Comment: @SujeetSinha Yes Sujeet. I wrote a button click event in which the js function is called which inturn calls the modal window to pop up. I had to write like this because it had to do some processing before it loads so that it can display the content on the popup .

Comment: @SujeetSinha Actually on page refresh, the button click event is fired. so its calling the JS function which inturn is calling the modal popup.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if OnCommand is the correct event to use in this context. If you want the event to be triggered by click, use the click event :

```
<asp:button class="btn btn-default" id="btnTextView" runat="server" Text="View as Text" commandArgument="1234" OnClick="btnTextView_View">   </asp:button>
```

This should stop the problem you are facing with page refresh too.

Comment: I just gave it as an example. Actually in my code `commandArgument="1234"` has some Eval properties which are to be taken to code behind, do some processing and then show them on the modal window. so I used command argument.

Comment: Then the answer posted by @Sujeet should be more appropriate...just checking if the page is postback before adding the script...

Comment: I just tried it. Adding the postback is stopping the button click event also. Dont understand why.